# Spoiler tag: Unnecessary spacing?

Tags: support, spoilers

I've posted a question with my setup specs for more detail, where I thought I'd just throw them in a [spoiler] tag in order to make it unintrusive for the majority of people who won't really care.
But it seems like the resulting element is reserving all the vertical space that several lines of content would normally occupy, just with a blank space.
Why is that?
Is there a way to collapse the supplementary information into one single line's worth of space, only to be expanded upon a click by interested users?

[image]

Comment: If people don't want to read a paragraph of your question they can easily skip it... why even put it in a spoiler quote at all? It only makes it tedious for people that actually *want* to read that info. Another approach would be to move the info at the end of the question.

Comment: [Status declined in 2009](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5199/241919), but workaround on SO: [Creating "expandable" code blocks](/questions/376391/creating-expandable-code-blocks)